# Resin's Custom Authentication

Tags: forms, authentication, resin, authenticator

I'm glad stackoverflow exists at least there is traffic. Sorry for asking these here but posting a question in caucho forums takes weeks to appear apparently.

I was fallowing a guide to have a custom login form for my service, but the guide was written for Resin version 1 I guess, and I'm working on version 4 and there are some custom tags that I don't fully understand and even the documentation for Resin 4 has some errors.

The tags are the next ones:

```
<login-config> <auth-method>FORM</auth-method> <form-login-config>
<form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
<form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page> </form-login-config>
<authenticator id='MyAuthenticator'/>
</login-config>
```

Version 4 tags where changed but I don't quite understand the "foo bar" analogy. I did watch Rescuing Soldier Ryan movie so Foobar sounds a little unprofessional and misleading.

```
<foo:MyAuthenticator>
    <foo:foo>bar</foo:foo>
  </foo:MyAuthenticator>

<resin:FormLogin form-login-page="/" form-error-page="/" />
```

I'm not totally sure but he getUser() method doesn't exists in the com.caucho.security.AbstractAuthenticator documentation. The method is called getPassworduser(). I know, people make mistakes, at least I have, and a lot.

```
package com.foo;

    import com.caucho.security.AbstractAuthenticator;
    import com.caucho.security.PasswordUser;

    public class MyAuthenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator {
      private PasswordUser _user;

      public MyAuthenticator()
      {
        _user = new PasswordUser("harry", "quidditch",
                                 new String[] { "user" });
      }

      public PasswordUser getUser(String userName)
      {
        if (userName.equals(_user.getName()))
          return _user;
        else
          return null;
      }
    }
```

So, can someone be so kind to explain me a little bit the new tag syntax?
What if my package is called com.subpackage1.subpackage2?
what represents the "bar" element?
What comes first? `<resin:FormLogin ...>` or `<foo:MyAuthenticator>...</foo:MyAuthenticator>`
How can I link my form to the authenticator considering that they are both separate tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thank you to those who read it and maybe try to answer. I just found a very useful document on the resin 4 migration. The link is [here](http://www.caucho.com/resin-4.0/admin/config-candi.xtp). Basically I have to set my own path in the web-app tag like these:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://caucho.com/ns/resin" xmlns:mycustomtag="urn:java:com.my.package">
```

then I just use the tag like these:

```
<mycustomtag:MyClass>
  <mycustomtag:customAttribute>someAtributte
  </mycustomtag:customAttribute>
</mycustomtag:MyClass>
```

I hope this is useful for someone, please show your love and give me a thumbs up by voting my answer.

Comment: it appears it is not working I keep getting error 405 POST not supported and if I follow this guide http://wiki.caucho.com/Custom_Authenticator_with_FormLogin_and_UserInRole (as you can see they removed the POST method from the form) I just get all the sent data unencrypted into the URL. Any ideas of what could went wrong??

Comment: never mind, abstractAuthenticator doesn't have any support for POST method. It is actually working except for the fact that the session is not being set. I remember I read somewhere that when returning a principal from AbstractAuthicator the session gets set automatically (I might be wrong)

Comment: Ok I finally got it working, basically when you are working with abstractAuthenticator the returned principal becomes an attribute of the httpsession object. The attribute name is caucho.user.principal (there is no documentation about this) and you can call it with getAttribute() method. Remember to cast it into caucho.security.BasicPrincipal.